# Cannot reference my method in the main method with compilation error

Tags: java, methods

I created the following rock, paper, scissors game. I am trying to create a method called "winner" which tells the user who wins the game. I created a variable "end" which is the output of the method "winner". When I do $System.out.println(winner(weapon, computerWeapon)) it gives me a compilation error. Could someone please help debug this problem? I am a novice at java.

Error: Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method winner(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) from the type Game

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Game {
  String end;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String computerWeapon;
    System.out.print("Human, choose your weapon: ");
    String weapon = input.next().toLowerCase();
    int randomNumber =  (int)(Math.random()*(3));

    if (randomNumber == 0)  {
       computerWeapon = "rock";
    }
    else if (randomNumber == 1)  {
       computerWeapon = "scissors";
    }
    else  {
       computerWeapon = "paper";
    }
    System.out.println("Computer chooses: " + computerWeapon);


   System.out.println(winner( weapon,  computerWeapon));



}

  public static String winner(String weapon, String computerWeapon){
    if (weapon.equals("rock")){
      if(computerWeapon.equals("rock")) {
        end= "Tie!";
         }
         else if (computerWeapon.equals("scissors")) {
           end =  "Human wins!";
         }
         else if (computerWeapon.equals("paper")) { 
           end= "Computer wins!";
         }
    }
    else if (weapon.equals("paper")){
      if(computerWeapon.equals("rock")) {
        end= "Human wins!";
         }
         else if (computerWeapon.equals("scissors")) {
           end= "Computer wins!";
         }
         else if (computerWeapon.equals("paper")) { 
          end= "Tie!" ;
         }
    }
      else if (weapon.equals("scissors")){
      if(computerWeapon.equals("rock")) {
        end= "Computer wins!";
         }
         else if (computerWeapon.equals("scissors")) {
           end= "Tie!";
         }
         else if (computerWeapon.equals("paper")) { 
           end= "Human wins!";
         }
    }
      return end;

  }

}
```

Comment: I'd image the error is caused by your end attribute that is not static.

Comment: is there a way to make it static?

Comment: Do you even use it outside of the winner method? If not, then why not declare it as a variable in that method. (attributes can be declared as static by adding static in front of them)

Comment: You would just add a modifier: `static String end;`. Though I would agree with NielsNet - I am not sure you really want the variable to be declared at the class level anyway.

Comment: @NielsNet Thank you, I made it a local variable in the winner method.

Comment: @theboy88 you're welcome. However I'd suggest to read a little about object oriented programming. Because working in a static context is not 'the right way'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the non-static `end` variable from within the static method `winner()`, which is not correct.
To fix it, you can either set it as static, or make it a local variable inside the `winner()` method, since you are returning it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly;

- You can not make reference to static variable from non-static method. To understand this , you need to understand the difference between static and non-static.
- Static variables are class variables , they belong to class with
  their only one instance , created at the first only. Non-static  variables are initialized every time you create an object of the class.

In your code , `end` param is non-static. But you are calling this param from your static method which is `winner(..)` . You can't do this.

In your static method, you are trying to return string. Global variable `end` param will be inner variable in `winner` method. So change this code like this ;

```
public static String winner(String weapon, String computerWeapon) {
    String end = "";
    if (weapon.equals("rock")) {
        if (computerWeapon.equals("rock")) {
            end = "Tie!";
        } else if (computerWeapon.equals("scissors")) {
            end = "Human wins!";
        } else if (computerWeapon.equals("paper")) {
            end = "Computer wins!";
        }
    } else if (weapon.equals("paper")) {
        if (computerWeapon.equals("rock")) {
            end = "Human wins!";
        } else if (computerWeapon.equals("scissors")) {
            end = "Computer wins!";
        } else if (computerWeapon.equals("paper")) {
            end = "Tie!";
        }
    } else if (weapon.equals("scissors")) {
        if (computerWeapon.equals("rock")) {
            end = "Computer wins!";
        } else if (computerWeapon.equals("scissors")) {
            end = "Tie!";
        } else if (computerWeapon.equals("paper")) {
            end = "Human wins!";
        }
    }
    return end;

}
```